# How to send T.38 from a mac?

Tags: asterisk, fax, modem

I'm trying to set up a fax-server on a macintosh. I have Hylafax, and we're going to use an internet FOIP fax provider (Haven't decided who yet, that may be another question). The problem is how to get from Hylafax to T.38. I know of two options, but I'm not sure how to decide between them:

- T38modem

Advantages: It's only one extra program, and i know that I can compile it for the Mac. (well, At least I can get the H323 version working on a Mac)

Disadvantages: It is mostly undocumented and seems to be supported only by one guy in Russia.

- IAXModem/Asterisk

Advantages: It's well known, and well supported. We can pay for support. It presumably does the T38 with SIP correctly, so we don't have to worry about it.

Disadvantages: It's two separate programs. While I know how to get Asterisk on a mac, I'm not sure about IAXModem. (It's sourceforge, and linux, but compiling things for a mac isn't always straight forward...) It's also mostly undocumented.

Do these seem like an accurate listing of the pros/cons? Anyone have any other suggestions?

thanks.